# Promises must be handled appropriately in Firebase CLI data request

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to read data from a node after an onCreate event has been triggered in another node. Data from these nodes would then be sent to a Google Sheet. While there is no error reported when I build the function, there is a deployment error where the message "Promises must be handled appropriately" is shown. Here is my function:

```
export const copyAcceptanceToSheet = functions.database.ref('/****/{****Id}/****').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    const orderId = snapshot.ref.parent?.key
    const pharmacy = snapshot.val()
    const timeCreated = new Date

    const ****Base = admin.database()
    const acceptRef = ****Base.ref('/*****/'+orderId+'/*****'+pharmacy);

    acceptRef.once('value').then(async function (snapshot2) {
        try{
            const price = snapshot2.child('****').val()

            await jwtAuthPromise
            await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
            auth: jwtClient,
            spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
            range: '****Update!A:D',  // update this range of cells
            valueInputOption: 'RAW',
            requestBody: { values: [[timeCreated, price, pharmacy]]}
            }, {})
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }

    })

})
```

The error message is for the line

```
 acceptRef.once('value').then(async function (snapshot2)
```

Comment: Your `onCreate`  callback is `async`  but you never `await` anything. Did you mean to `await` (or `return`) the `acceptRef.once('value')`  promise?

Comment: That is an error. I was initially calling sheets.spreadsheets.values.append outside the acceptRef.once('value'). Forgot to remove the async in onCreate. Edited the code, the error message stays

Comment: Adding one more comment so that in future someone refers to this question. async must be attached to the onCreate. Hence the original code that i had put is restored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), background functions must return a promise that resolves when all asynchronous work is complete.  This means that you must deal with any promises returned by API calls that work asynchronously.  All Firebase APIs are asynchronous in this way.  Right now, you function ignores the promise returned by `once().then().catch()`.  Simply calling `then` or `catch` on the promise doesn't fully "handle" the promise - they are just attaching callbacks.

Since you are using async/await, there is no need to even use `then` and `catch`.  Just `await` the promise returned by `once()` and continue dealing with the result.

```
const snapshot2 = await acceptRef.once('value');
const price = snapshot2.child('****').val()
...
```